# mysql create trigger error

Tags: mysql, laravel

Been having issues creating trigger for enforcing foreign key check on MyISAM engine. Any suggestions? Please find error below.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ERROR 1644 (45000): Custom ForeignKeyError
>                       ELSEIF (SELECT CO' at line 8 (SQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_user_permission                 
BEFORE INSERT ON user_permissions 
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE users.id=new.user_id)= 0 THEN                        
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Custom ForeignKeyError'
                    ERROR 1644 (45000): Custom ForeignKeyError
                ELSEIF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM permissions WHERE permissions.id=new.permission_id)= 0 THEN
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Custom ForeignKeyError'
                    ERROR 1644 (45000): Custom ForeignKeyError
                END IF;
            END;)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last part of you error generating statement. Just use

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Custom ForeignKeyError';
```

Don't forget the `;` at the end of that statement.

Depending on the tool you use to define the trigger you need to define another delimiter also.

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER insert_user_permission                 
BEFORE INSERT ON user_permissions 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE users.id=new.user_id)= 0 THEN                        
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Custom ForeignKeyError';
    ELSEIF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM permissions WHERE permissions.id=new.permission_id)= 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Custom ForeignKeyError';
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Not getting the parse error anymore.